# Ensure steam download IO writes are to secondary drive

Tags: steam, hard-drive

I have a main SSD drive where my Windows 7 is installed. I installed Steam on my secondary HDD.

I am downloading new games through the Steam client on the HDD. I know that the downloaded files are going to my secondary drive. However, can I get a confirmation that my main SSD is not getting written to during this process? (want to keep my SSD life up.)

Answer (score 1):

I can't verify it, but i assume it does not touch your primary HDD unless there is caching involved.

Open Taskmanager, go to the Performance tab and click the "Resources" button. There you check the Disk area. Close all programs and windows updates. Anything that does disk access for now. Then start downloading a game from steam. Sort by the "write" column.

If there is caching involved I assume the same amount of data is written to C: then D:

Watch and learn. And come back and tell us  :P